# How to delete 30 day older files and keep last day files for each month in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, datetime, powershell-2.0, delete-file

Deleting all files older than 30 days can be done using below cmdlet but I want to retain last day backup for each month. My backup file contains date format yyyymmddhhmm with no equal prefixes.

> information202107170102.7z
>
> testdatbase202107170242.7z
>
> otherdb202107170245.7z

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$path = "C:\Some\Path"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you are not using the embedded text date, only the file info. if that is what you actually intend, then please REMOVE the unneeded file name stuff. ///// you can us the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group by month, sort that by date, and throw out all but the last item. that will keep your "last of month" file.

Comment: Why not just enable [Windows Server FSRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/fsrm-overview) to monitor and move files at the enterprise level? [Create a File Expiration Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/create-file-expiration-task). There are many docs on Windows FSRM on the MSDocs site, all over the web, and on Youtube. The above talks move, you can use the same for delete as well.

Comment: I believe file management tasks are not applies to all windows servers, it has its own limitation and it is reserved for specific windows server version.

Answer (score 0):

This functions takes a date object and returns the last day of that month:

```
function Get-LastDayOfMonth{
param(
[System.DateTime]$date
)
    $next_month = $date.AddMonths(1).Month 
    while($date.Month -ne $next_month){
        $date = $date.AddDays(1)
    }
    return $date.AddDays(-1)
}
```

I'm sure you can make it work with this helper function.

Comment: ..or simply `(Get-Date -Year $date.Year -Month $date.Month -Day 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)`